# Javascript centering a div on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For javascript I use the jQuery framework but can easily integrate any javascript functions into it. The problem I have is I have a div that fade's in when I click a link. How can I get it to align in the center of the page and stay even when scrolling.

Below is an example of what I currently have implemented:

HTML code:

```
<div id="dividname">
    <h2>Heading Goes Here</h2>
    <p>content goes here</p>

    <p><a href="#" class="close-box">Close Box</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#dividname {
    position:absolute; z-index:100; width:600px; height:600px; display:none;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        // on click show div
        $('a.popup').click(
            function() {
                $('#dividname').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, it must work in IE6. I don't want to support IE6 anymore but some of my clients analytics show that enough people access the site with IE6

Comment: Also thanks everyone for your answers, I have not had a chance to test any of them out yet. I will let you all know how well they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [modal div](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) for jquery

This tool will take care of the moving for you if the user scrolls

```
// to show
$.blockUI({ message: $('[id$=div]'),
    css: 
    {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -300px;
        margin-left: -300px;
    }
 });

// to hide                                    
$.unblockUI({ message: $('[id$=div]') });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used many of their plugins before. Works great!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#dividname {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Where `margin-top` and `margin-left` is half of `height` and `width` respectively.

Comment: Likely the simplest solution. However, won't work in IE6, not sure about newer IEs.

Comment: Position: absolute. That will center the div just fine in all a-grade browsers (IE 6 and above included).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your style to this,

```
#dividname {

z-index:100; width:600px; height:600px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;

}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Btw, here's a hack to get it to also work in IE6,

```
* html #dividname {
 position: absolute;
 top: expression((document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) +
 Math.round(17 * (document.documentElement.offsetHeight || document.body.clientHeight) /
 100) + 'px');
}
```

(Taken from the jqModal Style Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep it centered with scrolling you will need to attach a function to move it to your scroll position.

You can do that with:

```
$(window).scroll(resize())
```

Get your current position with:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

This will comply with IE6 issues.